# How to create a minimap in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

I have a platform application with a series of platforms in an array and a player. Since the map is quite large, I would like to implement a minimap to keep the player from being lost/confused. What is the best way to implement this (the way with the least resource consumption)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your whole level is in a big display group, you could save the image to a file, load it in and scale it down to the size of your minimap.